# Why does my nav float left when I change the position to fixed? How do I fix that issue and keep it centered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.sunContainer').height() ) {
      $('.nav').addClass('stick');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('stick');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
}

#wrapper {
  height:3000px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.nav {
  width: 90%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#FFB00F;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.tab_holder {
  width:1000px;
  text-align: center;

}

li {
  width:120px;
  height:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;

}

li:hover {
  background-color:#2F4F4F;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

.imge {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sunContainer {
  background-color:#187249;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}

.third {
  background-color: khaki;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='sunset.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body id='body'>
    <div id='wrapper'>

      <div class='sunContainer'>
        
        <div class='nav'>
          <ul class='tab_holder'>
            <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>The Kidd Frankie</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Find a picture of the rising sun  -->
        <img class='imge' src='one.jpg'>
        <img class='imge' src='two.jpg'>
        <img class='imge' src='three.jpg'>
        <img class='imge' src='four.jpg'>
      </div>

      <div class='content'>
          Stuff will be here
    </div>

    <div class='third'></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='sunset.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

While just experimenting and playing around I ran into an issue. The issue being that whenever my nav adds the class it just floats left. At first I thought it was because I wasnt adding anything in the .stick class but realized that isnt issue. Anyone ever run into this issue? Seems like its a css problem and not the js. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With `position: fixed;`, you have to give a `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` to position it in your window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are centering your nav using `margin: 0 auto`. But when it gets assigned `position: fixed` by that `.stick` class, this centering method won't work anymore - it only works for  `position: relative` elements.

Since there is no other parameter in your CSS, as a fixed element it's simply placed at the default position `left: 0`

You can avoid that by assigning `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);` to it.

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.sunContainer').height() ) {
      $('.nav').addClass('stick');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('stick');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#wrapper {
  height:3000px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.nav {
  width: 90%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#FFB00F;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.tab_holder {
  width:1000px;
  text-align: center;

}

li {
  width:120px;
  height:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;

}

li:hover {
  background-color:#2F4F4F;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

.imge {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sunContainer {
  background-color:#187249;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}

.third {
  background-color: khaki;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='sunset.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body id='body'>
    <div id='wrapper'>

      <div class='sunContainer'>
        
        <div class='nav'>
          <ul class='tab_holder'>
            <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>The Kidd Frankie</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Find a picture of the rising sun  -->
        <img class='imge' src='one.jpg'>
        <img class='imge' src='two.jpg'>
        <img class='imge' src='three.jpg'>
        <img class='imge' src='four.jpg'>
      </div>

      <div class='content'>
          Stuff will be here
    </div>

    <div class='third'></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='sunset.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would it be ideal to just set the position left: 50? or is that just naive?

Comment: You mean 50px or 50%? 50px will simply create a fixed distance, which is okay, but not centered (or only then, if the window is exactly 100px wider than your nav). Simply giving it `left: 50%` would move the left border of the nav to the middle of the window, which definitely isn't centered, but too far right. Thats what the `transform: translateX(-50%)` is for: It moves the nav back left by half of its own width.